# overlapping elements in grid layout

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game i add child object prefabs to a grid layout dynamically,

But the problem is when i do this the child objects overlap:

[image]

If i do this without code, the problem disappears but i want to do it through code.

instantiation code is fairly simple:

```
go = Instantiate(CardPrefab) as GameObject;
// go.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = card.GetSprite();
go.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = GC.GetSprite(1, card.GetIndex());
go.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);                
go.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Player1ScrollPannel").transform);
```

what is the solution?

there is nothing attached to my card prefab, just an image and a button as a child:

[image]

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you have tried?  Like have you gotten the GridLayoutGroup and tried any of its methods to see if it will do this for you?

Comment: Can you show the settings of the Card prefab? What's attached to it in the Inspector tab?

Comment: @Programmer I Updated the question...

Comment: That's weird. Change the Spacing (x) to 50. Just increase it and see if that helps

Comment: What if you instantiate it with the Player1ScrollPannel as the parent rather then setting the parent afterwards?

Comment: @Programmer i tried this and nothing get better. that is really weird...

Comment: @Eddge at first that was as the parent, i just created another panel to see if the problem happens again, And it did.

Comment: so you attempted to instantiate it with this `Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent); `?

Comment: @Eddge Yes i did and exact same problem...
oh god!

Comment: @Alireza.pir just clarifying, that you understood what I mean as instantiating it with a parent, instead of instantiating the parent with it already as a child =)

Comment: Create new canvas and try. Also is any other object parent of the panel?

Comment: @Programmer I tried so, same problem...

No, panel is child of Canvas

Comment: Are you aware that your constraint is set to only allow a row of 1?

Comment: @Eddge yes that is what i want it to be :)

Comment: Can you show us your anchor? on your target?

Comment: @Eddge does it matter?
because grid layout MUST override this settings and fit child on itself

Comment: @Alireza.pir I would say yes it matters, since I cannot duplicate your problem.  As I am trying to recreate it I would need to know everything about how your objects are set up.

Comment: I did a quick replicate with your settings and it works fine. What's your Unity version? Call `Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases()` and see what happens

Comment: @Alireza.pir Grid Layout group will only override if the child does not say to ignore it, which is why Programmer asked "Can you show the settings of the Card prefab? What's attached to it in the Inspector tab?" earlier

Comment: @Programmer Unity 5.5.1f1
nothing changed...

Comment: I was finally able to recreate this,  The Grid Layout Group only enforces it's IMMEDIATE children to follow its layout, in your case you have an image which has a button under it, that button is not forced to the same standard.

Comment: That's the issue. The scale should be 1,1,1 not 8,8,8. Do not change the scale of UI component with the Scale tool. Change the width and height with the Rect tool.

Comment: @Programmer no that wasnt the issue, i changed the scale to 1,1,1 and still the problem exist!

Comment: @Alireza.pir Show us your buttons transform rect, if it isnt the scale issue that draco18s mention then the "button" most be way bigger then the image above it.

Comment: That was the only way way I was able to replicate this issue. Make sure **save** the changes on the prefab. If the changes is not done on the prefab then it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I haven't really played with layout groups, but...

70 pixels times a scale of 8.34 results in a final size of 583.8, but you're asking your layout group to arrange things in 106 pixel-wide cells.

In pulling up Unity and shoving a few images with a high scale value into a layout group...I get the same behavior. You either need to remove the scale `(1,1,1)` or change the layout cell size.

Comment: After reading this I was able to recreate it this way as well,  I completely missed the scale portion because my #1 rule with working in unity is to never touch the scale value on UI.

Comment: @Draco18s i did remove the scale and applied to prefab, but still the same problem...

Comment: @Alireza.pir Can you show the inspector on the clone inside the layout group?

Comment: @Eddge The only thing I touch scale-on-UI for is text, as at `(1,1,1)` it looks too blurry, so I scale it down to `(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` and double the font size.

Comment: @Draco18s I use TextMeshPro(Since its apart of unity now) instead of the normal Text.

Comment: here is the image:
http://s8.picofile.com/file/8331610192/3.png

the inner box is the cloned prefab inspector, 
its scale is changed!

is that a problem?
could it be because i use "Scale With Screen Size" option on canvas Scaler?

Comment: @Alireza.pir can you add that to your original post and use the image tags... some people answer question during down time at work and cannot access external links.

Comment: @Alireza.pir Does your layout group object have a non-`(1,1,1) ` scale?

Comment: @Draco18s no, its set to 1,1,1

Comment: @Alireza.pir Hmm. The prefab *is* getting scaled when added to the layout group. Only thing I can suggest is to set the instantiated prefab's local scale back to `(1,1,1)` after adding it to the layout group.

Comment: @Draco18s yes that solved the problem, but i am so confused why this happens!
we actually bypassed the problem by this way

Comment: @Alireza.pir All I can tell you is that *something* in the hierarchy is messing with the scale (when an object moves from World Space to being inside another Transform, it keeps its same *absolute* scale for convenience). Its possible that its the canvas scalar, I'm not sure